# Not operator in Matlab behaving strangely

Tags: matlab, math, floating-point

In my code I need to check if  pairs of the differences between two consecutive members of a vector are equal/not equal and then do some stuff accordingly. 
Now here is a strange thing happening in Matlab say if I have a two pairs of two consecutive numbers so when I use

```
(x(i+3) - x(i+2)) ~= (x(i+1)-x(i))
```

it gives me a `1` even if both sides are equal.
I think the reason is there is some round off error but not quite sure. For example,

```
x = [0,0.16,0.32,0.48,0.64,0.80];
>>a = x(5) - x(4)

a =

 0.1600

>>b = x(4) - x(3)

b =

 0.1600

>>a-b

ans =

5.5511e-17
```

Any idea how to get rid of this problem? Is there any different strategy to bypass `~=` or `==` operators for this ind of problems?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Why not just check if the difference in the two numbers you're comparing is less than `epsilon`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not compare floating-point numbers for equality that way. A more reliable way is to use `abs(a-b)<eps` if you are testing for equality.

Comment: Thanks! Did not know that Matlab has a macro for lowest machine precision.

Comment: @ArunavDev MATLAB does not have macros, [eps](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eps.html) is a function.

Comment: I might suggest the test as something like: abs(a-b) < 10*eps(a) for best results.

Comment: @woodchips. Good point for demonstrating eps(a). Here a relative precision suggests a fight against cumulated float rounding operations. But how could you guess what these ops were ? Since you don't know, then why 10 and not 2, 100, 1000 or sqrt(eps) or... ? And why not an absolute precision if this better fits the problem (like those data represent measurements in meters and measurements precision is 1mm) ? Strict equality will hardly ever work, but there's nothing like a universal error bound too, that's deep magic and wizardry and that's not what we want to preach, or is it?